# Как вывести alert если пользователь забанен (423 ошибка), при клике на кнопку выводить окно что пользователь забанен?

Tags: javascript, laravel, alert

Всем привет, Друзья!
У меня возникла проблема, делаю проект на ларавел 5, на php написана функционал, при забаненом пользователе.. Когда пользователь забанен в консоле есть 423 ошибка (locked), и мне нужно сделать чтобы при клике на кнопку добавить сообщение, у пользователя появлялся алерт что он забанен, как это правильно реализовать помогите пожалуйста  ?

Comment: document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  alert('Вы забанены');
});

Comment: а подскажите пожалуйста, как учесть то что пользователь забанен ? если там все на php

Comment: добавить php конструкцию if else которая в случае бана пользователя будет выводить кнопку на которую вы вешаете обработчик с alert уведомлением, а если не забанен, то вставляет кнопку для незабаненых.